# Error: null value in entry: blameLogFolder=null

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, null

I am getting this error in Android Studio while doing a Gradle build.

```
Error:null value in entry: blameLogFolder=null
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Delete the .gradle directory in root project folder and rebuild the project. I suppose that's a gradle bug.

Comment: i'll try this but didn't help for me. If you have other solution then please tell me. @KCK

Comment: Try clean project and rebuilding (although that didn't work for me)... as answered by @Nick Stampoulis

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a bug in gradle.
I toke another way, downdate of gradle version, I changed two lines:

In build.gradle(project)

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
}
```

And gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was downgrading like Cabezas said, and then reupgrading after I deleted all the subdirectories in the most current version directory of gradle which can be found here: ..\AndroidStudioProjects\<YourProjectName>\.gradle

Answer (score 1):

If deleting the `.gradle` directory isn't working (just like me), then try clean project and re-build the project.